# Por que usar "SELECT * FROM tabela" é ruim?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-select

Frequentemente é dito que pegar todas as colunas de uma tabela através do comando `SELECT * FROM tabela` é uma má prática. Qualquer recomendação sem explicação não é útil. Então...

Se é uma má prática, deve haver um jeito de usá-lo adequadamente. Deve haver uma situação em que não cause problemas. Se fosse sempre ruim, provavelmente nem existiria a possibilidade de uso.

- Quais problemas são causados pelo seu uso?
- Estes problemas ocorrem sempre? Há como contornar? Ou há situações que não faz diferença?
- As recomendações são válidas para qualquer banco de dados?

Comment: Resumidamente é para você não pegar mais dados do que precisa, se você quer só o valor `id`, não tem necessidade de trazer junto outras 50 colunas.

Comment: Em 99,9% é ruim , um exemplo que não tão ruim não invalida a regra geral.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Não é ruim/má pratica usar *wildcards* (`*`). Depende do seu objetivo.

### Quero ser um bom programador (provavelmente, seu caso)

Um bom programador sabe que ou ele vai precisar de **todas** as colunas de uma linha (por exemplo, em uma listagem estilo "mostrar todos os dados") e vai usar `*` ou vai usar **uma** ou **somente algumas** (em uma *subquerie*, por exemplo) e vai selecionar SOMENTE aquelas que precisa.

Como bom programador, você sabe que colunas serão adicionadas às suas tabelas, e você sabe que a única maneira de tornar seu sistema escalável - funcionando sem alterações -  é usar um *wildcard* (`*`). Um *framework* em geral, usa os metadados do BD para descobrir quais colunas existem, ou ainda, possuí isso em suas configurações. Mas essas informações são cacheadas por alguém, seja em um host rodando as aplicações, como de PHP, seja o host do BD. Essa tarefa sempre fica com alguém.

Mas em *joins*, onde unimos tabelas diferentes, podem aparecer colunas com nomes iguais (agora e futuramente), e a melhor forma de fazer isso é especificando coluna-a-coluna, pois assim usaremos "apelidos" diferentes para colunas com mesmo nome.

### Dinheiro curto

Bom, você ou é alguém responsável pelo orçamento dos projetos, ou é consciente de que deve minimizar dinheiro gasto no BD. Há servidores que limitam o tráfego, em termos de **números de *queries***, e outros que limitam por **quantidade de dados trafegados**. Em geral, você só vai se atentar aos `*` quando não pode trafegar muitos bits, ou ainda, quando a etapa de levantamento de requisitos (etapas anteriores à programação) estabeleceu que serão muitos registros no BD ou haverá uso intenso de rede.

Ah, se houver tráfego intenso de rede, o número de *queries* passa a ser problema, porque você economiza bastante em dados trafegados, mas não tem muito o que fazer com acesso múltiplo/concorrente (daí você já entra em teorias [CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem)/[ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), mas daí já foge do escopo de programação básica e em geral não se usa SGBDs e usa-se NoSQL).

O preço da Internet está cada vez menor, e os preços vêm caindo - de servidores de BD; dessa forma, você cada vez menos vai se preocupar com como seu sistema vai acessar o BD e mais em como ele se apresenta para o usuário.

### Bom, quero meu cliente (ou chefe/minha empresa) na minha mão (não vai conseguir).

Bom, antigamente, alguns programadores tinham a má fé de ignorar os princípios de programação e queriam "manter o emprego/cliente". Achavam que dificultar mudanças no sistema seria a maneira, e dessa forma, nunca/pouco usavam *wildcard* (`*`). Pois isso mudou muito: o que interessa são os dados que estão no BD, e não o sistema que o usa.

Se você estudar um pouco, verá que é fácil descobrir tudo sobre um BD - que não foi você quem fez - e dessa forma, saberá como o sistema deveria funcionar. Isso se chama engenharia reversa. E ainda, vendo o sistema funcionando, existe a reengenharia, que é fazer um sistema emulando outro.

Ou seja, não existe mais dependência do cara que criou a *query* sem *wildcard*, e você irá ser demitido ou irá manchar sua reputação no mercado com outros clientes.

### Resumindo

*Não há fundamento nesse apontamento atualmente* (antes, na era do bit lascado, sim), e você provavelmente sempre usará *wildcard*, a não ser em *joins*, onde colunas com nomes iguais podem aparecer de tabelas diferentes e tratar isso é mais difícil.

---

Acho que o pessoal que "negativou" não entendeu. ***Tudo depende do objetivo***, e ele pode mudar. Hoje, entreguei um sistema para o cliente e ele está 100% adequado ao que ele pediu. Mas amanhã pode não estar (cliente pede manutenção). Se pensarmos sempre em "um sistema preparado para o futuro", iremos encher a solução de teoremas, criando um software pesado, grande e complexo, que irá dar uma nota negativa para você hoje. Um software robusto deve ser usado para problemas que exigem robustez, mas não para casos em que muito provavelmente o sistema não irá ter necessidades maiores.

Comment: Acho que o pessoal que "negativou" não entendeu. Tudo depende do objetivo, e ele pode mudar. Hoje, entreguei para o cliente e ele está 100% adequado ao que ele pediu. Mas amanhã pode não estar. Se pensarmos sempre em "um sistema preparado para o futuro" iremos encher a solução de teoremas, criando um software pesado, grande e complexo, que irá dar uma nota negativa para você hoje. Um software robusto deve ser usado para problemas que exigem robustez, mas não para casos em que muito provavelmente o sistema não irá ter necessidades maiores.

Answer (score 32):

`SELECT * FROM Tabela` é considerada uma má prática porque não são especificados os campos que devem ser projetados para o retorno da consulta.

Toda vez que você utilizar `*`, é necessário que o banco de dados entenda quais são os campos existentes na tabela para montar a consulta correta (uma consulta nos metadados da tabela). Isso gera um certo *overhead* para o banco de dados.

Se você precisa consultar valores, teoricamente você deve saber quais valores que deseja retornar, isso otimiza a consulta. O custo de retornar 1, 2, ou 15 campos são diferentes, sendo assim, é boa prática e, ganha-se performance quando informados os campos de retorno da consulta.

**Exemplo:**

Suponha que você tem uma tabela com 10 linhas e 10 colunas. Você precisa fazer um `select` nessa tabela. Suponha:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela10por10;
```

Se cada campo na tabela tem 32 bytes de tamanho, o seu retorno será do tamanho: `32 * 10 * 10 = 3200 bytes`.

Se o que você precisa é de apenas um campo, então o melhor seria:

```
SELECT campo1 FROM Tabela10por10;
```

O resultado para essa busca é: `32 * 1 * 10 = 320` bytes. Apenas 10% do que retornou na consulta não otimizada.

**Para entender mais**:

Para entender as otimizações desse tipo, é necessário entender a [Álgebra relacional para banco de dados](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81lgebra_relacional).

***Editado***

> ... fora o *overhead* evitado pelo banco de dados (consulta nas tabelas de metadados).

Anteriormente havia presumido que informar os campos que deseja projetar na query evitaria a consulta aos metadados. @Trinidad corrigiu nesse equívoco. Fica afirmado então, de acordo com @Trinidad, que informar os campos que deseja selecionar/projetar não evita a consulta do SGBD no metadados.

> Isso gera um certo *overhead* para o banco de dados.

O tal *overhead* ocorre sempre, já que os metadados do SGBD é sempre consultado. De acordo com @Trinidad.

***Acréscimo***

**A semântica**

Como complemento a resposta, acredito que um dos maiores problema no `select * from Tabela` é o sentido semântico da consulta. Quando se escreve:

```
SELECT 
  Nome 
FROM 
  Cliente;
```

Está claro que o que deseja é o cliente. Até em consultas mais complicadas é possível entender o objetivo da consulta, como por exemplo:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(Total) AS TotalDaNota
FROM 
  ItemNotaFiscal;
```

O `SELECT *` não nos informa nada sobre o objetivo da consulta (a semântica - o significado), o que dificulta muito, principalmente, na manutenibilidade do sistema.

Comment: Você disse que não é bom pois o SGBD precisa consultar os metadados, porém estou certo que o SGBD *sempre* consulta os metadados, essa explicação ai sinceramente é balela.

Comment: Sim, você tem razão @Trinidad. A consulta nos metadados é sempre feita pelo SGBD. Vou corrigir minha resposta quanto a esse aspecto, porém, todo o resto está correto. Obrigado pela correção.

Comment: Acho que o ponto principal da resposta é o acréscimo. A performance não é o melhor ponto desta resposta porque não fundamenta como e quando ocorre perda de performance relevante. E não é em todos os casos.

Comment: Talvez eu esteja confuso, mas qual o motivo de enviar um `select *` se você quer apenas o campo1? Quero dizer, se enviar um `select *`, vai retornar 10 campos.

Comment: Há poucas situações em que você seleciona somente um campo; por exemplo, em subqueries. Use apenas um campo se mesmo adicionando OUTRAS COLUNAS o significado não será alterado. Por exemplo, se for dividir um campo nome em dois (nome e sobrenome), você irá ter que alterar a querie (além do sistema) mas se você tiver usado wildcard(*) só precisa alterar no sistema (e dependendo de como o sistema foi feito, nem precisa). Mas se os outros campos da tabela gerarem um tráfego de dados grande (consultar minha resposta), você voltará a usar campo-a-campo.

Answer (score 27):

## *"Quais problemas são causados pelo seu uso?"*

O problema todo é que você estará (*preguiçosamente*) não especificando quais colunas você deseja da sua cláusula `SELECT`:

- **Ineficiência pela quantidade**: Você estará manipulando um volume de dados que não precisa. Pense na transmissão de rede do banco de dados para a aplicação, ou o *data set* gerado na aplicação em si; você poderá está consumindo mais memória e maior banda de rede sem perceber.
- **Ineficiência pela indexação**: Talvez você só precise utilizar colunas indexadas pelo banco; nesse caso se tivesse selecionado somente estas colunas a operação seria menos custosa.
- **Confusão de nomes de colunas**: Em seu *SELECT* podem estar envolvidas colunas com mesmo nome (muito comum em *joins* extensos). Isso pode gerar problemas não só para algum *ser humano* lendo o resultado de sua query tanto como também algum sistema interpretando esse resultado.
- **Não fica explicíto o sentido da query**: Fica mais claro para outra pessoa (ou até para você mesmo tempos depois) o que aquela query está fazendo. Um exemplo simples é: imagine que está para ser removido do banco de dados uma coluna. A maneira usual é passar query por query vendo quais utilizam tal coluna; no caso destas queries com asterisco não basta verificar apenas a query, mas passa a ser necessário verificar toda manipulação feita com o resultado selecionado (verificando se a tal coluna é mesmo utilizada).

## *"Ou há situações que não faz diferença?"*

A única situação que já ouvi dizerem que não faz diferença é no caso de:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...
```

**Mas** também já ouvi dizer o contrário (que faz sim diferença). Talvez esse comportamento seja diferente de SGDB para SGDB (talvez varie até entre versões do mesmo).

Não preocuparia em pequenos testes; em produção sempre utilizei `SELECT COUNT(0) FROM ...` por precaução.

## *"As recomendações são válidas para qualquer banco de dados?"*

Quando falamos dos principais SGDBs com certeza sim; é raro fugir disso.

Mas hoje em dia existem uma infinidade de sistemas de banco de dados; convém *dar uma conferida* quando surgir esse tipo de dúvida qual comportamento exato do banco de dados que estiver utilizando.

Comment: Só para deixar claro, `COUNT(*)` é algo totalmente diferente de usar `*`.

Answer (score 14):

Muitos já deram as mais importantes razões:

- prejudica o desempenho porque retorna mais dados que o necessário, incluindo os não indexáveis.
- é menos legível, não se sabe que dados são realmente relevantes no retorno.
- não explicita qual o nome de qual coluna, o que é importante quando se faz joins. Os SGBDs geralmente sabem lidar com isso, mas fica menos claro.

Há, porém, ainda outra razão muito importante:

- O código que usar o resultado da busca pode, em alguns cenários, ficar acoplado à ordem das colunas no banco.

Se você tem a tabela abaixo...

```
CREATE TABLE pessoa (
    id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    nome     VARCHAR(100),
    endereco VARCHAR(200)
);
```

...e você usa uma API que retorna os result sets como um array numérico, como abaixo...

```
ResultSet results = query.execute('SELECT * FROM pessoa');

for (Result result : results) {
    String name = result.get(1);
    String endereco = result.get(2);
    // ... mais código aqui
}
```

...seu código vai depender de que a primeira coluna da tabela seja o id, a segunda seja o nome e a terceira o endereço. Isso pode, porém, mudar; por exemplo, assim;

```
ALTER TABLE pessoa ADD COLUMN sobrenome AFTER nome;
```

Pronto: seu código acima já não funciona.

Isso pode não ser tão importante se os resultados funcionarem como dicionários/maps - `String nome = result.get('nome');` - mas ainda assim o cenário acima é importante.

(Note que quase tudo aqui é pseudocódigo, não garanto que o código rode :) )

Answer (score 10):

> Quais problemas são causados pelo seu uso?

Do ponto de vista técnico há perda de performance porque:

- pode exigir ler mais informação no armazenamento de massa que é mais lento
- pode exigir que uma consulta que bastaria pegar dados do índice tenha que fazer *lookup* na tabela principal e ler isso
- pode aumentar o consumo de memória e diminuir chances de cache de outras coisas (sim, isso pode afetar a performance de outras *queries*)
- o aumento do consumo de memória pode exigir que a seleção de resultados seja jogado no armazenamento de massa temporariamente, o que é muito mais caro. E pode inibir o uso de certos algoritmos mais performáticos quando há risco de não estar tudo na memória
- a transmissão de tantos dados é mais demorada e pode custar mais se a rede tiver medição (vai, põe na nuvem! :) )

Mas há casos, raros, que pode ocorrer o contrário e uma consulta que poderia ser reaproveitada não o é porque pega menos colunas. Então não é uma verdade absoluta.

Em termos de performance qual é a diferença entre usar o `*` e listar todas as colunas? Duvido que seja diferente de zero, e se tiver é irrisória, é só por causa da forma de consulta ao metadados.

## Real problema

Mas na verdade o maior problema não é técnico, é conceitual: é **não pensar no que está fazendo**. É ruim usar `*` porque as pessoas fazem isso por preguiça. Se ela souber o que está fazendo, quais as implicações, se for o que ela deseja não tem problema alguém usar.

E o problema maior ainda é que as pessoas não sabem de todas as implicações do seu uso. Além da performance, ela não entende que isso torna a aplicação dela dependente da estrutura do banco de dados. Se ele mudar a ordem das colunas na tabela ou se o banco de dados fizer isso de forma diferente por algum motivo, pode ser que a aplicação dela não funcione mais (é verdade que a maioria das aplicações são muito burocráticas e nem se valem de mecanismos sofisticados que seriam afetados por isso). Claro que depende da aplicação. Quando você conceitua errado algo pode dar errado no futuro.

Pode parecer "babaca", mas querer **todas as colunas** do banco de dados é semanticamente muito diferente de querer **cada uma das colunas, sem exceção**. Use o que você quer. É claro que se a pessoa falha em interpretação de texto ela não pode decidir corretamente o que fazer. Se a pessoa não é detalhista, comete erros que nem percebe.

É claro que há contextos que fazer de um jeito ou de outro vai mudar nada. Como toda recomendação que parece "boa prática" precisa de contexto.

O que eu entendo é que se a pessoa não sabe o que está fazendo, por padrão não deveria usar o `*`, porque ele tende causar mais dano que usar. Mas as pessoas que mais precisam seguir o padrão mais seguro por padrão são justamente as que menos optarão por ele.

Então usar os nomes das colunas é tão ruim quanto asterisco se você não pensar sobre o que está fazendo.

> Estes problemas ocorrem sempre? Há como contornar? Ou há situações que não faz diferença?

A questão técnica até ocorre virtualmente sempre, mas em baixos volumes ela é ínfima e mesmo que seja proporcionalmente grande, o todo é baixo e não importa muito.

A conceitual claro que ocorre sempre, só não quer dizer que ela trará problemas reais sempre. Tem gente que dá sorte. Ou então trabalham com outros problemas tão mais graves que este se torna irrelevante.

> As recomendações são válidas para qualquer banco de dados?

As conceituais, sim, claro.

A técnica não necessariamente, embora seja altamente provável.

Respondi porque acho que faltava algo assim e no fundo era o que eu queria saber. Hoje tenho mais confiança que isto é o mais correto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

Realmente é melhor utilizar os nomes ao invés de `*`, porém isto não significa que o comando não pode ser utilizado ou que é ruim. O `*` é muito útil quando você faz uma consulta apenas para consultar direto no SGBD (Sistema Gerenciador de Banco de Dados).

Agora se você for trabalhar com estes dados com uma linguagem de programação é muito melhor colocar os campos por questões de performance e organização. (Isto não significa que você não pode usar um `*` (*all*) ), pois em sistemas muito pequenos pode ser muito mais fácil colocar o `*` do que todos os campos que você quer (Não que seja a melhor solução).

Agora se você estiver em uma empresa, ou se você tiver fazendo um projeto sério seria inviável colocar todos os campos uma vez que você não irá utilizar todos.

O `*` é utilizado para fazer consultas direto no SGBD, facilita o tempo em que você digita e é muito útil.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora a partir do tempo que você faz consultas em um sistema é muito melhor uma query que retorne dados  mais rápido.

```
 select Host, User, Password from user
```

Desta forma as consultas retornarão muito mais rápido além de os campos serem mais fáceis de ser visualizados (que esta segunda opção é mais uma frescura pessoal, não interfere no performance no sistema, apenas na organização do código). O único motivo relevante de não usar o `*` é que não o utilizando os dados retornam muito mais rápido, melhorando a performance do sistema.

Answer (score 5):

Quando você usa uma cláusula `SELECT`, você pode especificar a lista de colunas ou expressões:

```
select Coluna, Coluna, ..., Coluna from Tabela
```

Ou `*` (asterisco) como lista de seleção:

```
select * from Tabela
```

**Evite** o uso de asterisco (`*`) em instruções `SELECT`, principalmente devido a **motivos de desempenho**, pois a busca em todos os campos será custosa a medida que o tamanho da tabela aumenta.

**Use isso durante o desenvolvimento/testes**, para visualizar parte do conteúdo da tabela para o desenvolvimento de consultas, usando por exemplo o `TOP` para exibir apenas a quantidade de registros desejada:

```
SELECT TOP (100) * FROM tabela
```

Comment: o TOP controla a quantidade de dados verticalmente, enquanto evitar o uso do * horizontalmente. A ideia da tabela ir crescendo é mais significativo para condições sem WHERE e com TOP do que em relação ao *

Comment: Uma analogia caseira, select * seria trazer a sopeira, o concha do feijão, a taça de vinho, etc para o café da manhã, se não vai usar não traga ...

Answer (score 0):

Dizem que usar `SELECT * FROM tabela` é ruim porque **normalmente você não precisa nem de todas as colunas e nem de todas as linhas da tabela**.

Se a tabela tiver poucas linhas, usar query assim não tem nenhum ônus, mas veja esse exemplo:
O cara tem uma tabela de mais de 10 mil registros, com 25 colunas, faz `SELECT * FROM tabela`  para carregar em um componente JavaScript, que exibe apenas 4 colunas, e mostrar na tela. Isso é um erro.

Por quê?

- Porque uma pessoa não visualiza 10 mil registros ao mesmo tempo.
- Porque o navegador do usuário vai travar.
- Porque o custo de trazer 10 mil registros do servidor para a máquina da pessoa tornará a execução lenta.
- Porque trazer todos os campos da tabela, quando normalmente você quer apenas uns 3 ou 4, será ainda mais lento.

Como sair desse impasse?

- Incluir no lugar do asterisco os nomes dos campos que você deseja.
- Usar a cláusula `WHERE` para filtrar e trazer apenas os registros que interessam.
- Criar índices para as colunas utilizadas nas cláusulas `WHERE`.
- Paginar os dados usando `LIMIT`, passando o ponto de início e a quantidade de registros que deve ser trazida na query.

Comment: Na verdade poder ter ônus sempre, mesmo que ele seja pouco relevante em pequenos volumes. Isto ocorre principalmente quando as colunas que realmente interessam estão nos índices, eliminando assim a busca na tabela. Afeta também porque pode dificultar otimizações. Veja as demais respostas. O asterisco só a afeta as colunas, não as linhas.

Comment: Sim, sei que os asteriscos só afetam as colunas, mas como ninguém falou nada a respeito de não incluir nenhum filtro no select e isso poder trazer mais registros do que o necessário achei interessante incluir na resposta. Inclusive um filtro com WHERE para reduzir o número de linhas retornadas, e LIMIT para paginar os registros, a meu ver, é mais relevante para melhoria do desempenho do que redução do número de colunas. Na primeira vez que li a pergunta não me atentei que ela era referente exclusivamente ao * para as colunas e por isso minha resposta ficou mais geral para otimizações.