# Como fazer SELECT de todos os campos menos alguns?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query

É sabido ([e já foi perguntado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21583/por-que-usar-select-from-tabela-%C3%A9-ruim)) que deve-se evitar usar `SELECT *` em alguns casos em consultas ao banco. Mas imaginemos que eu tenha uma tabela com 50 colunas, e eu queira selecionar 40 delas.

Só o fato de selecionar os campos já deixaria a consulta gigantesca, exemplo:

```
SELECT campo_1, campo_2, campo_3, campo_4, campo_5, campo_6, campo_7, ....
```

Minha pergunta é, existe alguma forma mais simples de informar que eu quero todos os campos **MENOS** alguns?

Comment: É sabido mais ou menos :) Há controvérsias (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22835/101). Ainda não surgiu uma resposta única lá que mostre todos os pontos importantes, que mostre que há casos e casos, mas lendo todas as respostas dá uma ideia mais ampla sobre o assunto. De qualquer maneira a pergunta em si é boa.

Comment: @bigown Basicamente, se você precisa de todos os dados, use `*`, se não, busque somente o que você precisa, mais campos resultam em perda de performance.

Comment: Eu diria diferente, se você precisa de alguns campos e precisa de performance e **mediu** que usar o * seria problemático, e que sua aplicação não precisa receber as colunas que existem na tabela (a aplicação vai saber lidar com colunas que a aplicação nem previa) em oposição a receber colunas específicas (eu percebo que a maioria dos programadores não sabem fazer softwares flexíveis), e estou citando só algumas restrições para escolher listar os campos, o * é melhor opção. Escolher quase todos ou todos é a mesma coisa em quase todos os casos. Claro que tem que ver o caso específico.

Comment: Algumas respostas dependem de que forma os dados são usados, um relatório simples pode receber um tratamento de metadados para que uma eventual nova coluna seja acrescentada de forma automática mas para um cálculo sempre será preciso alterar a lógica.

Comment: @Kazzkiq com um tratamento de cache correto, a perda de performance por ter todos os campos na consulta não chega a ser significativa ;)

Comment: Só pra complementar, não há problema nenhum na query ser "gigantesca" por este aspecto. O que pode ser sinal de problemas é query __complexa__ demais, o que independe do tamanho "texual".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Isso **não** é possível com SQL Server nem com Oracle. Não sei se é possível com outros bancos, como MySql. Se alguém souber, fique a vontade para editar minha resposta.

A especificação do select do Oracle se encontra aqui: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm

E do SQL Server, em Português: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189499.aspx

Algumas pessoas podem sugerir [<strike>gambiarras</strike> alternativas com código](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea), que fazem uma consulta no *schema* da tabela para obter os nomes de todas as colunas exceto as que você especificou. Isso só torna o código mais complexo e pode virar um pesadelo de manutenção depois.

Além disso, para muita gente é considerado má prática obter todas as colunas **exceto** um grupo específico. O motivo é que especificando o nome de cada coluna que você quer, você garante que sua consulta trará **sempre as mesmas colunas**.

Imagine que você faz uma consulta que retorna todas as colunas que existem hoje, exceto `foo`. Se amanhã eu criar a coluna `bar`, sua consulta trará todas as colunas anteriores, exceto `foo`, mas incluindo a nova coluna `bar`. **Sem mudar sua consulta, eu alterei o formato dos resultados**.

Se você seguir adiante com isso, as pessoas que forem dar manutenção no seu código vão lhe amaldiçoar até o fim dos tempos.

Comment: +1 pela resposta perfeita.

Comment: "Se você seguir adiante com isso, as pessoas que forem dar manutenção no seu código vão lhe amaldiçoar até o fim dos tempos." Fato!

Answer (score 11):

Se você for usar com frequência esses dados, te aconselho criar uma view para os mesmos. E depois você ainda pode criar "select's" dessa view.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF54694

Answer (score 4):

Mas a pergunta também é interessante, tal como a [questão do wildcard(*) no select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21583/por-que-usar-select-from-tabela-%C3%A9-ruim).

Você quer fazer um sistema flexível/escalável. Que funcione mesmo com novas colunas. Daí você faz um sistema que busque quais colunas existem (metadados) e exclui aquelas que você tem certeza que não irá precisar. Muito que bem, você está criando um sistema preocupado com tráfego de dados (considerando que é feito cache dos metadados, é claro) mas não tráfego (quantidade de queries).

Só que você passa esse overhead para o servidor de aplicação, pois como nosso amigo Renan disse, não criaram isso em SQL (geraria muito overhead para o BD, pois apesar de a lógica ser simples, precisaria ser feita em todos os tipos de consulta). **Ganhou em dados, perdeu em desempenho.** Lógico que o desempenho perdido depende da disponibilidade da sua aplicação. Sistemas que não têm problemas com acesso múltiplo/concorrente não têm problema com isso.

Agora, outro apontamento. E se a coluna que foi adicionada semanticamente tiver que ir para a lista das exceções? Hum, e pior ainda, se seu significado pedir que outras colunas das listadas (trazidas sim pelo select) entrem nas exceções? Piora: e se ....

Muito que bem, esse problema tem uma solução, chamada parametrização. o usuário ou um arquivo de configuração - ou ainda outro sistema - definem os campos entrantes e não-entrantes da query.

Problemas? Sim, parametrização é um dos paradigmas mais debatidos da programação: como parametrizar, o que parametrizar, quando, e assim por diante. Sim, porque isso **gera código mais difícil de criar e fazer manutenção** apesar de diminuí-la.

Parametrização aumenta o overhead também (*principalmente do programador*).

Mas tudo isso podia ser resolvido com o wildcard (*); pois o sistema que está fazendo é simples. Ou só algumas colunas.

Answer (score 4):

Só para adicionar uma informação.
Até onde eu sei, o `SQL` não permite isso (ainda?), porém algumas linguagens/ferramentas têm opções de banco de dados que podem fazer esse papel, como o `SAS`, que possui a opção `DROP=`, onde se indica quais os campos serão ignorados.

```
select * 
  from tabela(drop=campo200 campo5000);
```

Comment: Não é recomendado o uso deste espaço (Resposta) para observações, aguarde até que tenha privilégio para comentar.

Answer (score 3):

Encontrei uma solução não performática, mas que funciona.

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM NOME_SUATABELA


ALTER TABLE #TEMP
DROP COLUMN COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2...


SELECT * FROM #TEMP
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

- Insira todo o resultado que necessitar em uma tabela [Temporária](http://www.devmedia.com.br/tabelas-temporarias-no-sql-server/2610).
- Remova as colunas que não irá precisar no Resultado.
- Tudo pronto, agora basta executar um comando `select` a tabela Temporária.

Comment: Provavelmente não é uma solução muito performática pra ser usada em produção (já que você precisa replicar a tabela inteira a cada execução), mas é uma ótima alternativa para uma query periódica (ex.: gerar relatórios) que rode em um ambiente mais controlado. Solução muito interessante.

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi essa questão com esse Select aqui usando IN na SQL do MySQL

No caso eu tenho vários perfis de uso do sistema mas na hora de cadastrar um novo uusário (variando o perfil de uso do usuário eu exibo para seleção somente os que quero que apareça na tela

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE IdPerfil, Nome_Perfil 
FROM usuarios_perfil 
WHERE Nome_Perfil IN ('Administrador','Cliente') 
ORDER BY Nome_Perfil 
DESC
```

Não sei se isso te ajuda

Answer (score -2):

Solucionei este problema usando uma forma lógica. No campo que não quero agrupar, converto ele em randômico. Veja um exemplo:

```
SELECT codigo,locador,mes,descricao, iIf(recibo = 999999999999999, rand()*516241235432165, recibo)  As recibo, Sum(valor)  
FROM CONTA
GROUP BY codigo,locador,mes,descricao, recibo
ORDER BY CODIGO
```