# Como selecionar todas as colunas menos uma em específico?

Tags: mysql, sql, estilo-de-codificação

Existe a possibilidade de selecionar todas as colunas de uma tabela:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_rw_programacao WHERE id = $id
```

Mas estou precisando eliminar do resultado a coluna `id`. É possível?

Comment: Não é possível. A não ser que você crie uma função pra fazer isso.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não é possível pegar todas colunas menos uma ou algumas específicas.

Geralmente [pegar todos já costuma ser um erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21583/101), fica pior quando tem exceções.

Quase sempre que alguém quer fazer isto é para digitar menos. Isto não é adequado.

Se quer pegar uma lista específica deve colocar todas elas. Se quer todos, ou seja, se mudar quer que as colunas diferentes sejam mudadas na *query* automaticamente, aí cabe o `*`. Quase nunca é o que a pessoa quer.

Faça da forma semântica correta que precisa.

Se quer realmente que venha a lista de colunas total menos uma teria que tratar isto fora do SQL.

Até existe uma solução automatizada onde você pode ler os dados do MySQL sobre esta tabela e gerar a *query* a partir disto, mas só deve fazer se realmente precisa que a *query* seja dinâmica de acordo com a estrutura atual.

Tem um exemplo de como fazer na resposta do Wictor Chaves (mas note que é fácil ter problemas de segurança se abusar disso se não souber bem o que está fazendo, principalmente se esse `$id` vier de fonte externa). Mas não faça isso para economizar digitação, seu código estará semanticamente errado se não é o que precisa e mesmo que não traga problemas agora trará no futuro.

Para fazer isso funcionar o sistema todo precisa ser feito pensando nisso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

Desta forma você consegue:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), '<columns_to_omit>,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table>' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database>'), ' FROM <table>');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Substitua `<table>, <database> e <columns_to_omit>`

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql

Answer (score 6):

Pode chamar os campos que desejar fazendo assim, exemplo:

```
SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4 
FROM wp_rw_programacao 
WHERE id = $id
```

Os únicos campos que vão ser retornados serão: `campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4`

> Mais [informação](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp).

Não existe outra forma de ser feito. Veja aqui mais informações no [StackOverflow<sup>pt</sup>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22905/como-fazer-select-de-todos-os-campos-menos-alguns).

Comment: Porém tenho muitas colunas.

Comment: @AtilaSilva eu tenho umas 60 colunas e seleciono na mão cada uma =] É uma chatice, mas nem sempre programação é divertido

Comment: Trabalho do cão para eliminar uma coluna , só para complicar o código , não vi uma razão para isto.