# Query no MySQL para chamar dados da tabela

Tags: mysql

No caso do uso da *query* `SELECT * FROM`, existe a possibilidade de trazer todos os dados da tabela, porém sem requisitar 1 ou 2 colunas?

Pois no caso de uma tabela enorme, é muito mais fácil se houver essa maneira(que eu tenho certeza que existe), do que digitar todas a colunas no padrão `SELECT w, x, y ,z...`

Comment: Já existe uma pergunta semelhante aqui. [Por que usar “SELECT * FROM tabela” é ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21583), [Como fazer SELECT de todos os campos menos alguns?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22905), [Como selecionar todas as colunas menos uma em específico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247484)

Comment: Não tem como, precisa dizer só as colunas que se deseja mesmo. Já tem uma outra pergunta aqui sobre o assunto, e também uma resposta que explica porquê não é bom fazer `SELECT * FROM table`

Comment: Não e não faz diferença porque quase toda API joga as colunas numa matriz associativa e você só usa as colunas que precisa.