# Como fazer busca por ID no MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo um sistema de entrada e saída de veículos da empresa, no index fiz 2 inputs um de `entrada` e outro `saída`, quando clico em entrada aparece a tela de cadastro do veiculo como `placa, nome do motorista, data da entrada e hora da entrada`, quando clica em inserir eu coloquei pra gerar um protocolo que puxa do `id`.

Com a saída do veículo eu estava sem ideia daí resolvi fazer o seguinte, Quando o veiculo for sair da empresa a pessoa clicar lá em saída aparacer um botão procurar, daí eu coloco o protocolo e aparece a placa do motorista e o nome do mesmo, pois não estou conseguindo fazer o sistema de procurar, me ajudem com o sistema de procurar, segue abaixo o código do entrada:

```
if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {

$placa      = isset($_POST["placa"]) ? $_POST["placa"] : '';
$nome       = isset($_POST["nome"]) ? $_POST["nome"] : '';
$dataentrada  = isset($_POST["dataentrada"]) ? $_POST["dataentrada"] : '';
$horaentrada  = isset($_POST["horaentrada"]) ? $_POST["horaentrada"] : '';
$observacao = isset($_POST["observacao"]) ? $_POST["observacao"] : '';
$id = "id";

$sql  = "INSERT INTO entrada(placa,nome,dataentrada,horaentrada,observacao) VALUES('$placa','$nome','$dataentrada','$horaentrada','$observacao')";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql);

$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entrada");
$resultado1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1) or die (mysql_error());

echo ('<center> <b>
Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!
      </b> <br />
Seu protocolo é: #' . $resultado1["id"] . ' </center>'); } ?>
```

**CÓDIGO DO HTML DA ENTRADA**

```
<form action="" method="post">
Placa:                       <input type="text" name="placa" /> <br />
Nome do Condutor (0pcional): <input type="text" name="nome" /> <br />
Data de Entrada:             <input type="date" name="dataentrada" /> <br />
Hora Entrada:                <input type="time" name="horaentrada" /> <br />
Observação:                  <textarea name="observacao" cols="30"> </textarea> <br />
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Registrar" />
```

Comment: Apenas uma nota: estamos em 2014, o PHP6 ja está em desenvolvimento e mysql ja foi *deprecated* (será removido), isso significa que numa atualização no PHP do seu servidor no futuro fará seu código parar de funcionar, o que não é muito legal, já que isso está sendo produzido para uma empresa. Então tome cuidado para manter o servidor da empresa usando PHP5 ou o projeto vai parar de funcionar, ou, como alternativa, vocẽ pode usar as novas funções que substituem o mysql: a classe **mysqli** e a classe **PDO**. Ainda vai demorar alguns anos para o PHP6 lançar e ser comum nos servidores, mas... ;)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, irei me atualizar , rsrs.

Answer (score 3):

O mais fácil é você usar o comando  mysql_insert_id() pra pegar o último ID inserido, após você fazer o INSERT, e com isso você elimina o select.

Ficaria assim:

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO entrada(placa,nome,dataentrada,horaentrada,observacao) VALUES('$placa','$nome','$dataentrada','$horaentrada','$observacao')";

$resultado = mysql_query($sql);
$idinserido = mysql_insert_id();

echo ('<center> <b>
Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!
      </b> <br />
Seu protocolo é: #' .$idinserido . ' </center>');
```

Comment: Também não utilize mais a biblioteca mysql_*, é insegura e inconsistente. Utilize a biblioteca mysqli_* ou PDO.

Comment: @Marcelo Gomes, funcionou vlw.

Comment: @gcarvalho97 beleza, vou começar a me atualizar ;D

Comment: @PauloPimentel se a sugestao do Marcelo funcionou, aceite esta resposta como a solucao!

Comment: @OnoSendai, Ajudou em outro problema, mas o problema da pergunta continua sem resposta, rsrs

Comment: Paulo, você tem dois campos com "name" igual, ou seja, name=id... só o campo deve ter esse name=id...
retire o do form, e deixe apenas no do campo...
<form action="" method="post" --->  name="id" <--- >
<input name="id" type="text" />
de resto, me parece que o seu codigo lá debaixo está certo.. só não vai funcionar se o campo principal da tabela não for ID ... pode ser "codigo" ou outro nome qualquer. Confira na sua tabela se o campo se chama realmente "id".  Lembrando que minusculas e maiusculas fazem diferença nos nomes dos campos mysql.

Comment: Ahh, acabei de ver... você tá fazendo uma atribuição errada... isset() retorna só verdadeiro ou falso.. e não o conteúdo da variável... você precisa tirar o isset da atribuição... ponha somente assim:
 $id = (int)$_POST['id'];

Comment: @PauloPimentel olhe os comentários que fiz acima.

Comment: @MarceloGomes Amigo, eu resolvir o problema, não estou em casa agora, quando chegar em casa vou mostrar a solução a você, desde já obrigadaooo, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 2):

Como você não define o `id` no código o mesmo deve estar sendo auto-incrementado no banco, portanto o que procura é provavelmente o maior valor:

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM entrada");
```

Note que é jamais se recomenda usar o `SELECT *` veja [esse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21583/por-que-usar-select-from-tabela-%C3%A9-ruim/21589#21589) para mais detalhes.

E esse código não é seguro pois somente estou pegando o maior valor, se quiser que o seu código fique mais seguro sugiro usar isso:

```
 $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM entrada ORDER BY id DESC WHERE placa = $placa LIMIT 1");
```

Seleciona na tabela os ids por ordem decrescente e verifica se a placa é a mesma informada e só pega o primeiro resultado (para caso haja placas iguais).

**Nota:** tome cuidado para não permitir que o seu sistema aceite placas iguais.

Comment: Amigo é o seguinte as placas podem se repetir, pois o mesmo veiculo pode entrar no dia seguinte ou até no mesmo dia, por isso criei o protocolo que puxa do id, o que preciso é fazer com que busque por protocolo(id), ou seja qualquer protocolo(id) que eu inserir lá ele aparecer os resultados desse id tipo, nome e placa ou seja o que eu determinar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

$id = (int) isset($_POST['id']);
$protocolo = isset($_query['id']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE id = '$id'");

while ($dados = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

echo $dados['placa'];
echo $dados['nome'];
}
}
?>

<form action="" method="post" name="id">
<input name="id" type="text" />
<input name="enviar" type="submit" />
</form>
```

O código buscar de saída, porem não consigo buscar o id de acordo com o que coloco ;s