# Especificar campos que eu não quero no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-select

No MySQL, quando vamos fazer um `SELECT`, geralmente podemos especificar cada campo que queremos retornar.

```
SELECT id, nome FROM usuarios
```

Porém, imaginemos um cenário onde eu tenha **50 colunas** em uma tabela e eu não queria que sejam exibido os campos `senha` e `email`.

Seria mais fácil, logicamente, eu especificar que eu não quero esses **2 campos**, do que selecionar os outros **48 campos** restantes que quero que sejam exibidos

Existe alguma maneira de se fazer isso no MySQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As soluções apresentadas funcionam, apesar de estranhas, vou só dar algumas alternativas para o problema. Não necessariamente soluções como pedido na pergunta (se é que existe real solução para isto):

- [Use o `*`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21583/101). Se vai pegar várias colunas, eliminar uma ou outra provavelmente não trará muita vantagem, em alguns casos pode até ser desvantajoso.
- Se vai usar muito este tipo de seleção, [crie uma visão](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) com as colunas desejadas.
- Crie *script* gerador de código ([*scaffolding*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119731/101)) que lê o banco de dados e gere pelo menos parcialmente as *queries* para você. Fica mais fácil apagar alguns campos ou o *script* pode até saber o que deve retirar.

As duas últimas são consideradas [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) e só abordagens diferentes de obter o mesmo resultado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 pelo DRY(dont repeat yourself) do segundo item  aplicado na criação da `view`. Pois teríamos uma definição em um lugar só que seria utilizado em vários outros lugares :)

Comment: Pensando bem, por que ainda não existe uma solução simples (como `NOT SELECT <column>, <column> FROM <table>`) no SQL ANSI?

Comment: Até poderia existir mas provavelmente é pouco usado, raramente faz sentido e pode trazer alguns problemas obscuros. Acho que dificilmente é a intenção. Até dizer que você quer tudo é comum, o `*` foi feito para isto, ele diz claramente que você quer até as colunas que você não sabe se existe. Dizer que quer tudo, até o que pode ter sido adicionado depois menos tais colunas é bem raro ser necessário. Filtrar uma ou outra coluna pode custar mais caro que pegar todas, então é melhor que seja mais explícito do que quer.

Answer (score 7):

Uma outra solução seria simplesmente omitir o valor dessas duas colunas:

```
SELECT *, NULL as senha, NULL as email FROM usuarios;
```

O `NULL` ali pode ser substituído qualquer valor que você queira mostrar por padrão nestes campos.

Comment: Também tirado do `SOEN`? acabei de ver essa no link do amigo @LuisHenrique. Muito boa!

Comment: Verdade! Mas essa eu não tirei de lá. Sempre faço isso pra omitir o hash das senhas :)

Answer (score 4):

Pode utilizar o seguinte select:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), '<columns_to_omit>,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table>' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database>'), ' FROM <table>');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Substitua os campos `<table>`, `<database>` e `<columns_to_omit>`

Retirado do SOEN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql

Comment: Nosso Deus! parece meio que uma gambiarra isso, mas mereceu um + 1 :)

Comment: Realmente é uma gambiarra isso, pois você seleciona o nome de todas as colunas internamente e da um replace nelas por nada, montando a query principal que no seu exemplo vai ter 48 colunas.