# Número de colunas influencia em performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, desempenho

Quando modelamos um banco de dados, o número de colunas pode interferir na performance?

```
Ex: Tabela1 possui 2 campos, 1 int pk e 1 nvarchar(50)
    Tabela2 possui 50 campos, 1 int pk e 49 nvarchar(50)
```

`Select` usado para ambas as tabelas, indiferente do tamanho de colunas:

```
select Id,Nome from Tabela1
select Id,Nome from Tabela2
```

Comment: como o bigown apontou, a melhor estrategia para herança, vai depender da sua necessidade, em todo caso, aconselho que leia este comparativo entre TPH, TPT e TPC: [How to choose an Inheritance Strategy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/15/tip-12-choosing-an-inheritance-strategy.aspx)

Comment: @TobyMosque opa..então, relacionado a herança no EF...eu nunca usei, até tentei uma vez...Mas preferi não usar para não ficar acoplado...

Comment: apesar do artigo se referir a dicas quanto ao EF, este capitulo em especifico se aplica a qual quer ORM, ele aborda justamente como a estrategia da criação das tabelas afeta o desempenho, integridade, flexibilidade e a estética... devido a algumas limitações de alguns ORMs, não é interessante ter uma tabela para cada objeto, uma unica tabela representando o objeto base e os seus derivados vai apresentar um melhor desempenho, em contra partida varias tabelas pode melhorar a validação dos dados no banco, flexilidade em incluir subtipos e a estética do mesmo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tudo pode interferir na performance, mas aí entra a questão de precisar ou não. Certamente influencia, mas muito pouco e proporcional. Na verdade proporcional amortizado porque algumas operações não farão diferença quantas colunas tem.

Existem muitos motivos bem mais importantes que vão influenciar a performance.

Não se preocupe com isso. Se precisa de muitas colunas, coloque. Se não tem motivo para elas existirem, não tem porque criá-las. Se tentar juntar dados em uma coluna para ter menos colunas, aí eu diria que piorará ainda mais a performance e gerará muita confusão. Não faça isto, o ganho será ínfimo ou nem existir.

Mesmo que tenha muitas colunas, [leia só as que você precisa naquela consulta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21583/101). Isto minimiza o impacto.

Ter muitos dados pode influir indiretamente na performance porque ele pode lotar o cache mais rápido e ter que ficar acessando disco com mais frequência. Mas note que o tamanho do dado total é mais importante que a quantidade de colunas, se puder diminuir a quantidade dados, faça.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: obrigado por responder, é que vejo alguns casos, que criam outras tabelas e referencia a FK, por ex, ContatoId, EnderecoId ...Mesmo que a tabela não seja 1-N, então fiquei com esta dúvida...

Comment: O motivo é outro. Ficar separando colunas em outras tabelas pode piorar a performance consideravelmente. Claro que cada caso é um caso. Existem situações que isto pode melhorar a performance na maioria dos casos e piorar nos casos extremos, o que pode ser uma boa troca. Mas tem que analisar o caso concreto. Tem gente que faz isso porque pensa orientado a objeto e não liga para a performance. Tem gente que faz porque não sabe o que está fazendo.