# performance em uma consulta do tipo select

Tags: mysql, sql

Para o SGBD o que é mais rápido receber os campos todos explicitados ou usar o caractere `*` que representa todos os campos. Caso haja diferença qual a razão?

```
Select coluna1,coluna2,coluna3, .....,colunaN from
```

Ou

```
Select * from
```

> A pergunta é bastante clara, `explicitar TODAS as colunas ou usar *` e, não obstante, gostaria de uma resposta objetiva focada somente nessa condição.
>
> Não é desejável que as respostas a esta pergunta sejam baseadas em opiniões mas sim em fatos, referências ou experiência específica.

Comment: Creio que quanto menos campos você solicitar, mais rápida fica a consulta. Mas vamos esperar os mais experientes falarem.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Número de colunas influencia em performance?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94825/3635) e [Por que usar “SELECT * FROM tabela” é ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21583/3635)

Comment: A pergunta foi bastante clara, "explicitar todas as colunas ou usar *" e não usar o que for necessario

Comment: Para o SGBD é mais rápido receber o comando com todos os campos explicitados. O uso do * obriga o servidor a consultar quais são os campos antes de efetuar a busca dos dados, criando mais um passo no processo.  Fonte http://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-select-guia-para-iniciantes/29530

Comment: Quando comecei a usar MySQL fui instruído a selecionar os campos que vou usar, ainda mais quando há muitos na tabela, ou quando vou fazer JOIN.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Isto não é totalmente verdade (ou seja é verdade mas não para todos os casos), cada motor tem um comportamento, pode ser que uma consulta com `*` seja otimizada para um tipo de motor mysql especifico, não dá pra afirmar nada, fora que de qualquer forma geralmente isso é **micro**-otimização e sendo assim dificilmente é este tipo de coisa que irá prejudicar o banco de dados, claro que depende muito do servidor, motor e/ou configurações.

Comment: @qualcuno leia as respostas desta pergunta, veja se lhe atende: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21583/3635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem algumas pesquisas que sugerem que deixar o campo explicito em uma consulta torna a consulta mais rápida, já que o uso do `*` o banco de dados deve procurar por tabelas existentes e só depois exibir o conteúdo delas. Depende muito do montante de dados que você possuí, mas o melhor é especificar quais colunas são. Se você utilizar o MySQL com PHP, e houver uma alteração na estrutura da tabela como adicionar uma nova coluna, pode resultar em danos significativos em seu sistema se a consulta for feita com o `*`, ou pode até mesmo fazer com que dados não importantes trafeguem pela rede utilizando processamento e banda larga desnecessária.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/07/18/the-real-reason-select-queries-are-bad-index-coverage.aspx