# Column 'idusuario' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

Estou tentando fazer um `select` com `inner join`. Rodando o `select` no *phpmyadmin* o **ERRO** que retorna é esse:

> Column 'idusuario' in where clause is ambiguous

```
<?php
$idusuario = $_GET['idusuario'];

    $getCli=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM enderecoUsuario INNER JOIN usuario 
                            ON enderecoUsuario.idusuario = usuario.idusuario 
                            WHERE usuario.idusuario=:idusuario");
    $getCli->bindValue(":idusuario", $idusuario);
    $getCli->execute();

    while ($linha=$getCli->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $idusuario = $linha['idusuario'];
        $nome = $linha['nome'];
        $sobrenome = $linha['sobrenome'];
        $logradouro = $linha['logradouro'];
        $bairro = $linha['bairro'];
        $cidade = $linha['cidade'];
        $uf = $linha['uf'];
        $email = $linha['email'];

        $return = array(
            'idusuario' => $idusuario,
            'nome'  => $nome,
            'sobrenome' => $sobrenome,
            'logradouro'    => $logradouro,
            'bairro'    => $bairro,
            'cidade'    => $cidade,
            'uf'    => $uf,
            'email' => $email
        );

    }

    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: WHERE usuario.idusuario=:idusuario

Comment: Isso ocorre porque no joins entre 2 ou mais tabelas existe uma coluna com mesmo nome. Você deve usar a referência de qual tabela deve exibir.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Esse erro significa que o banco de dados não sabe a qual coluna você está usando/referenciando pois esse nome existe em duas ou mais tabelas.

Para resolver isso é simples basta dar um alias para alguma das colunas ou nesse caso especificar o nome da tabela antes do campo.

Mude:

```
SELECT * FROM enderecoUsuario
INNER JOIN usuario ON enderecoUsuario.idusuario = usuario.idusuario
WHERE idusuario=:idusuario
```

Para algo como (opção com alias):

```
SELECT enderecoUsuario.*, usuario.idusuario as novo_nome_id FROM enderecoUsuario
INNER JOIN usuario ON enderecoUsuario.idusuario = usuario.novo_nome_id
WHERE usuario.novo_nome_id = :idusuario
```

Opção com o nome completo da coluna:

```
SELECT * FROM enderecoUsuario
INNER JOIN usuario ON enderecoUsuario.idusuario = usuario.idusuario
WHERE usuario.idusuario = :idusuario
```

Comment: Mas quero selecionar todos os dados das tuas tabelas

Comment: @GustavoSevero editei a resposta, lembre que no PHP campos/chaves com o mesmo nome tem seu valor sobrescrito com o último valor.

Comment: É que na tabela enderecoUsuario, é só os dados do endereço e na tabela usuario eu tenho o nome, sobrenome e email

Comment: Leitura interessante, mostrando prós e contras do `select *`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21583/64969

Answer (score 5):

Quando você busca dados em mais de uma tabela e elas possuem nomes de colunas repetidos você precisar informar de qual tabela a coluna é.
No caso você fez correto no `INNER JOIN` porém esqueceu de informar no `WHERE`.

> Column 'idusuario' in where clause is ambiguous

Coluna idusuario no where é ambigua, ou seja, o sql não sabe de qual tabela você quer filtrar. 
Ele precisa que você informa: `usuario.idusuario` ou `enderecoUsuario.idusuario` no `WHERE` também.

```
SELECT * FROM enderecoUsuario 
INNER JOIN usuario 
ON enderecoUsuario.idusuario = usuario.idusuario 
WHERE usuario.idusuario=:idusuario
```

Respondendo aos seus comentários, fica um pouco complicado nós depurarmos o erro sem ter acesso a base, mas vou tentar tornar minha resposta mais útil para você.
No link que você mandou o `idusuario=5`.

Verifique se existe usuário e endereço para esse ID, pois sua query depende da existência de ambos para retornar algo.

```
SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE idusuario= 5 -- Veja se retorna algo.
SELECT * FROM enderecoUsuario WHERE idusuario = 5 -- Veja se retorna algo.
```

Caso queira trazer todos os usuários mesmo se não houver endereço mude de `INNER JOIN` para `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: Beleza, não deu mais erro, mas colocando pra rodar no meu sistema não retorna nada!! Sendo que tem dados para retornar!

Comment: Certo, você precisa verificar que valor vem na variável $idusuario e se existe um usuario e um endereco para ele.

Comment: @GustavoSevero , você tem acesso para fazer a consulta direto no banco? Se sim, fica mais fácil examinar onde está o problema. Você pode trocar por `CROSS JOIN` ou coisa do tipo e investigar onde está acontecendo o filtro que remove os dados necessários

Comment: Tem, veja:
"detalhesclienteCtrl.js:10 http://reservacomdomanda.com/areaAdmin/api/admin_estabelecimento/clientes.php?opcao=2&idusuario=5"

Comment: @GustavoSevero faça a consulta e veja qual o filtro que está errado. Faça isso falando diretamente com o banco, para assim garantir que a consulta funciona, para só então descobrir como tornar isso factível com PDO

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece por que tanto na tabela ´enderecoUsuario´ quanto na tabela ´usuario´ existe a coluna `idusuario`.

Você poderia "selecionar" quais colunas precisa no retorno da query para não ocorrer esse conflito.

Exemplo : `SELECT COLUNA_A, COLUNA_B FROM ...`

Answer (score 2):

As tabelas `usuario` e `enderecoUsuario` tem uma coluna com o nome `idUsuario` indique qual a tabela junto com o nome da coluna no `where`.

Por exemplo: 
`usuario.idUsuario = idusuario`

Comment: Sim! por isso estou fazendo INNER JOIN.

Comment: Complementei a resposta com a correção na where