# Como pegar os dados de 3 tabelas com INNER JOIN de forma performática

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho três tabelas no banco sendo elas Treino, *Exercicio* e *Exercicio_Treino*.
Preciso fazer o `SELECT` com o `INNER JOIN` e diferenciar as colunas com o mesmo nome:

```
    SELECT t.id AS tid, et.id AS etid, e.id as eid, t.data AS tdata, et.data 
         AS etdata, e.data as edata, *
    FROM treino t 
    INNER JOIN exercicio_treino et 
    ON et.treino = t.id 
    INNER join exercicio e 
    ON e.id = et.exercicio;
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é se é correto fazer dessa forma ou se tem um jeito mais prático que digitar todas as colunas no `SELECT`

Comment: O que isso tem a ver com "ser performática"?

Answer (score 0):

Está correta a maneira que você esta fazendo, lhe aconselho apenas a fazer é colocar nomes mais significativos ao alias, alias é o nome que se da a este apelido da tabela, para facilitar sua chamada.

```
SELECT column_name AS alias_name
FROM table_name;
```

[Mais informações](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Answer (score -2):

Para pegar todas as colunas em um select voce deve fazer assim:

`SELECT * FROM` ...

[mas não é aconselhável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21583/por-que-usar-select-from-tabela-%C3%A9-ruim).