# Autocomplete com dados vindos do PHP

Tags: php, mysql, autocompletar

estou tentando criar um formulário pra registrar servições realizados, logo me deparei com o primeiro problema, estou tentando manter o mais leve possível pq são muitos dados. pretendo armazenar o "funcionário","cliente","serviços"... Optei por usar um input autocomplete trazendo o nome dos clientes do BD, porem quando passa dos 10 nomes ele para de funcionar.

listaclientes.php

```
<?php   
$query_clientes = 'SELECT * FROM clientes';
$result_clientes = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_clientes);
while ($linhas_clientes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_clientes)){  
echo '"'.htmlentities($linhas_clientes['nome']).'",';
}?>
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="autocomplete">Clientes: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<script>
var tags = [ <?php include_once("listaclientes.php"); ?>];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

O código gerado fica assim:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>autocomplete demo</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <label for="autocomplete">Clientes: </label>
    <input id="autocomplete">


    <script>
var tags = [ "Junior Santos","Michel","Cordeiro","Elton Costa","Mateus Eduardo","Eduardo","Deivinho","Rogerio Ribeiro","Sergio Ribeiro","Manuel Luiz Santos","Claudio Gomes","Evandson dos anjos        
","Edmilson Cabral      
","Junival alexandre        
","Brendo Luiz      
","Jessica Sabino   ","Jhonatas","Paulo Vitor","Rafael Casal","Jaison Felix","Rubens Arruda",];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
</script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que as quebras de linha estão gerando um erro de Javascript.

A solução é limpar estes caracteres especiais no `echo`:

```
<?php   
   $query_clientes = 'SELECT nome FROM clientes';
   $result_clientes = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_clientes);
   while ($linhas_clientes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_clientes)) {

      $nome = htmlentities($linhas_clientes['nome']); // Tratamento de caracteres especiais
      $nome = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), $nome);  // Remoção das quebras de linha

      echo '"$nome",';
   }
```

O `str_replace` troca os caracteres do primeiro parâmetro `array("\r", "\n")` pelo segundo parâmetro `''`, efetivamente removendo-os da *string*.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php

**Dica:**

em vez disto

```
$query_clientes = 'SELECT * FROM clientes';
```

Prefira isto

```
$query_clientes = 'SELECT nome FROM clientes';
```

Da primeira forma, mesmo você só usando o `nome`, vai trafegar todos os campos do DB para o PHP. Da segunda, estará só trazendo a informação que realmente precisa.

Mais detalhes em:

> [Por que usar "SELECT * FROM tabela" é ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21583/70)